# Docker registry on localhost does not work

Tags: debian, docker, docker-registry

I am using a private docker registry on the host `foo` with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  registry:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: registry:2
    ports:
    - 5000:5000
    volumes:
    - /tmp/myregistry:/var/lib/registry
```

I added at the host `foo` the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "localhost:5000" ]
}
```

And `docker info` shows:

```
Insecure Registries:
  localhost:5000
  127.0.0.0/8
```

(I really have no idea, where the second entry is from.)

But calling `docker pull localhost:5000/myapp` does not work. It simply does nothing and never returns. The same, when I call `curl -kv http://localhost:5000/v2/` ...

```
(root@foo)/etc/docker# curl -kv http://localhost:5000/v2/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:5000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

Using my vpn (openvpn), I can access the private docker-repository on this host and push the app (or do anything else).

```
(thomas@otherhost)~# curl -i http://foo:5000/v2/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 22:02:04 GMT
```

I can exclude a firewall problem. Any ideas? TIA!

PS: Some weeks ago, this works fine, and I have no idea, what has changed ... :(

Comment: The second entry is there by default, and it already covers localhost, so your own entry is superfluous. Check out the log files of your registry.

Comment: I found it. The logs of my registry does not show any error/warning, nothing about trying to connect.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce your issue. I started a registry using your docker-compose.yml, pushed an image to it and was able to pull it. It doesn't matter if I add the registry to the insecure registries or not.

Comment: Which OS are you using? (I have Debian bullseye)

Comment: Using a brand new installed ubuntu 22.04-LTS it works for me to :(

Comment: It is a firewall reason. If I disable whole firewall, it works. I do not understand it, but I have to check it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a docker, but a firewall problem.